# Why can I access to the Private properties when using constructor parameters inside the same class

Tags: c#

I have a working sample code, and I can not explain why this is working like this.

Take this class for example.

```
 public class TestClass
{
    private int _testValue;


    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var t = new TestClass() {_testValue = 42}; // Why is that working?
    }
}
```

Why is this allowed?
I would have expected having the behavior as this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        new TestClass() { _testValue = 23 }; // Does not compile and I am happy with that.

        // The code provided will print ‘Hello World’ to the console.
        // Press Ctrl+F5 (or go to Debug > Start Without Debugging) to run your app.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Go to http://aka.ms/dotnet-get-started-console to continue learning how to build a console app! 
    }
```

Edit: Tank you for your comments, but I know what private keyword mean, the question is, why Can I have access to the private properties when I am using a parameter constructor when I am inside the same object.
Place a debugger, you will see that the TestClass `this._testValue` is not the same as the `t._testValue`

The normal behavior in my mind is the one that I have in the Main function.

[image: Debugger.]

Comment: To which class does `Main` belong? If it´s different from `TestClass` you surely can´t access the private members of `TestClass`. However in the `TestMethod` 
 you surely can. Is that your question? Why a method within `TestClass`  cann access private members of `TestClass`?

Comment: You are allowed to access the `private` class members **from inside** the class' members. `TestMethod` is a member of `TestClass`, so you are allowed to access all `private` members from that method.

Comment: "this._testValue is not the same as the t._testValue" Sure, becauseyou create a new `TestClass`-instance within `TestMethod`, that has nothing to do with the current instance (`this`). Do you expect `this` to point to the same instance as `t`?

Comment: But why would `this._testValue` be equal to `t._testValue`? They are different instances, so of course their values aren't the same (unless you set them to the same value).

Comment: Honestly, this is something I never knew (or had even considered). TIL. Are there any practical use cases for this or was there no explicit intention to allow for this?

Comment: It's Private to the class not the instance. It's really wierd to come accross for the first time :)

Comment: Exactly is private regarding the syntax, do I am creating two DIFFERENT object, new reference, why can I access the private property in that case? This is really strange to me.

Comment: But private doesn´t care for the actual instance. There are two instances within two completely unrelated values. You can of course examine both, because you´re within that class.

Comment: If you understand what it is doing here, what is really the question? It works like this because someone decided that it should work like this. `private` means private to the class, not to the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to assume that `private` cares for the **instance** - which it obviously does not. In fact you don´t even need an instance - e.g. on a `static` member.

So if or if not you may access a member of a class depends on two factors:

1. are you within the same **scope** as that member?
2. do you have access to the instance to which the member belongs?

In your case your member is `private`, which makes the members scope the class-level. `TestMethod` is a method within that class, so point one matches.

You have two different instances. As you´re within `TestMethod` you can of course access the members of `this` (the current instance). Furthermore you have a reference to the newly created instance `t`. So point 2 also applies and you can access both members of both instances.

As an aside to point 2: If the member is static, there´s no instance, you can **allways** access it from within another instance.

Answer (score 4):

> [private keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private)
>   Private access is the least permissive access level. *Private members are accessible only **within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared***...
>   It is a compile-time error to reference a private member outside the class or the struct in which it is declared.

If you look at the documentation for the `private` keyword, the "key" part in relation to your question is that it is accessible within the body of the class and not restricted to access by only the same instance in which the private member or method is declared.

In your added example, `TestMethod` is in `TestClass`, so code in `TestMethod` can access any private methods or properties in its own instance and any other instance it has access to.

This is indicated in the quoted definition of the keyword: `TestMethod` is "in the body of the class in which `_testValue` is declared", so it can access those.

There is no restriction in the documentation that the access must be through a specific instance, so no matter how you create or have access to a new or different `TestClass` inside of `TestMethod`, you have access to that instance's private members and methods.

One of the reasons we have `private` is to keep internals away from unrelated code but to still provide access to the class it belongs to. This allows the class to manipulate instances of itself, which is incredibly important in copying *internal* data from one instance of an object to another. You don't want to make those `public`, because then any other unrelated code would have unwanted access.

This behavior of `private` is at least shared with C++ and TypeScript, and it probably common across most if not all programming languages the have `public` and `private` access.

Comment: I am sorry I do not see how this is an answer to my question, I just added a debug screen.

Comment: @pix: The answer is clear: _it is accessible within the body of the class and not restricted to access by only the same instance_.

Comment: @pix I've tried to add some further explanation that relates to the example you show, but the key is in the definition that relates to "within the body of the class" and not "within the same instance of a class".

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private):

> Private access is the least permissive access level. Private members
>   are accessible only within the body of the class or the struct in
>   which they are declared, as in this example:
>
> -snip-
>
> Nested types in the same body can also access those private members.
>
> It is a compile-time error to reference a private member outside the
>   class or the struct in which it is declared.

As for your screenshot.. 
The value of first `_testValue` is at 0 because that's the default value of int and you didn't set anything else otherwise when you created that object.

The new object you've created inside `TestClass` - you're explicitly setting a value of 23 to that and you do this because you have access to that property as per definition of the `private` keyword.

Comment: I think you ***do*** because it does answer your question which as you said is: "why Can I have access to the private properties when I am using a parameter constructor when I am inside the same object."

Comment: @pix But the definition of the `private` keyword answers your question.

Comment: @pix If the edit does not answer your question then I think your question isn't reflecting what you're assuming it should.

Comment: This is a really strange behavior, this is another instance. Why Microsoft or call it what ever you want, allow this behavior?

Comment: @pix It states the reason in the definition :)

Comment: @pix This "strange behavior" is, I believe, common across many if not all programming languages that have `public` and `private` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just refer to this specific part of your question - I think it should help you understand the behavior:

> Place a debugger, you will see that the TestClass this._testValue is not the same as the t._testValue

Now, some clarification to all those `private` keyword definitions people posted here. Both `private` and `protected` access modifiers refer to a `class` not an `object` - that means that if a property is marked as `private`, then any object of that class can access that private property in any instance of the same class, including different objects. That's why the definiton specificly say:

> Private members are accessible only within the body **of the class** or the struct in which they are declared.

It's the same if most (if not all) object-oriented programming language. The justification for that might be that if two objects belong to the same class, then they know how to properly and safely handle and use their private members - there is no point of restricting that access then.